# change default web server on spring-boot 2.4.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, webserver

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.4.4 and I would change the default web server Tomcat to undertow orJHetty but I find it very difficult using both Gradle or Maven.

An old documentation exposes how do it but I'm sure all is changed because now tomcat, undertow and jetty configuration is embedded in the core library:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

How do it in the 2.4.4 version?

Comment: Should be the exact same way. Here's the docs for the latest version: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-embedded-web-servers .

Answer (score 3):

*There are no changes between the versions.* This is well described right at the Spring Boot **2.4.4** Reference guide, right in **[3.1. Use Another Web Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.4/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-another-web-server)** section. Basically, the change consists of two steps:

1. Exclude embedded Tomcat server dependency from the `spring-boot-starter-web` artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

2. Include your embedded server as a separate dependency instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Just don't forget to notice the following quote from the reference guide in the very same section which might or might not be relevant to you:

> The version of the Servlet API has been overridden as, unlike Tomcat 9 and Undertow 2.0, Jetty 9.4 does not support Servlet 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

follow three steps to change the default web server, change configuration in **pom.xml**.

1.exclude the default web server.

2.Include the necessary web server.

3.Maven update.

For example,

Instead of this

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add this one

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for the necessary server add the appropriate web server dependency.